# What online software/websites are there that can review/analyse my website?

Tags: validation, web, analysis, review

Can anyone advise where I can have my website reviewed?

Is there an online forum for website critique?

What online software is there that can analyse my code?

Comment: The w3c validator for HTML, jslint for Javascript

Comment: for your html markup language mostly the W3 validator. For your code behind maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Anyway, the username + not posting the url here to start with, made me giggle a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) for checking HTML, and you can use [JSLint](http://jslint.com) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com) for Javascript.

Also, we have [a code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm more partial to JSHint.

Comment: @Renan I prefer JSLint :P but edited

Comment: thanks @doorknob - stackexchange and w3c exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will validate your HTML and CSS.